# In production I get the slf4j logger factory but in dev I always get the logback factory

Tags: java, maven, logging, logback, slf4j

My code is:

```
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
System.out.println(LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

On the production server I always get back `org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory` which is in turn an sfl4j `LoggerFactory`. However in dev I always get back `ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext`. Ultimately I want the logback `LoggerContext` because I then use in appenders as the context. For the life of me I can't see why.

I even looked at a solution that said it may be a racing condition due to conflicts and to do a while loop and sleep while waiting for the proper logger factory gets loaded but that didn't work. Also it's a hack and not an ideal solution.

The pom.xml list of dependencies is pretty big so unless there's an easy way to search through it to see what dependencies are clashing I can't imagine trying to do that effort manually...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well *something* has got to be different. If the logging level is off, you'll have a SubstituteLoggerFactory with NOPLogger as the delegate.

Comment: I agree. But for the life of me I can't figure out what is different. It seems like a racing condition with the dependencies but how do I debug that?